# SQL View between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view

I have two tables in my database that I would like to create a view that contains all the information.
One of the table holds details of each order, and the other table holds the general stuff of those orders.

Here is the details of the tables:

**OrderRecords_table**

```
OrderID|CustomerCode|Customer|Address|PickupLocation|TotalPrice|CreateTime
C00001 |AB001       |ABC Co. |CA     | Store        |5         |2015-01-01 
C00002 |BC002       |BC Co.  |CA     | store        |5.5       |2015-01-01
```

**OrderDetails_table**

```
OrderID|Company|ItemName|Amount|unitPrice|CreateTime         
C00001 |ABC Co.|apple   |1     |2        |2015-01-01 01:01:01
C00001 |ABC Co.|Orange  |3     |3        |2015-01-01 01:01:01
C00002 |BC Co. |candy   |5     |1        |2015-01-01 03:01:01
C00002 |BC Co. |pan     |1     |2        |2015-01-01 03:01:01
C00002 |BC Co. |ruler   |2     |2.5      |2015-01-01 03:01:01
```

Something like this, so on OrderRecords, orderID is unique, and orderDetails has a record for each item.

Right now I am creating a method that would need details from both tables, and it would be really confusing if I try to Select item each time across table, and I would like to create a view that contains details of both table.

I want it to be something as follow:

**View V**

```
OrderID|Company|CustomerCode|Address|ItemName|Amount|UnitPrice|CreateTime
C00001 |ABC Co.|AB001       |CA     |apple   |1     |2        |2015-01-01
C00001 |ABC Co.|AB001       |CA     |orange  |3     |3        |2015-01-01
C00002 |BC Co. |BC002       |CA     |candy   |5     |1        |2015-01-01
C00002 |BC Co. |BC002       |CA     |pan     |1     |2        |2015-01-01
C00002 |BC Co. |BC002       |CA     |ruler   |2     |2.5      |2015-01-01
```

What would the best way be to create such view? Thanks

Comment: Check out `mysql inner join` and in your case you will join with `OrderID` from both tables.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty thanks for editing it, i will take a look at the inner join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a join:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT orec.OrderID, 
       od.Company,
       orec.CustomerCode,
       orec.Address,
       od.ItemName,
       od.Amount,
       od.unitPrice,
       od.CreateTime
FROM   OrderRecords orec
JOIN   OrderDetails od ON orec.OrderId = od.OrderId
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but for the last part 
''FROM   OrderRecords or
JOIN   OrderDetails od ON or.OrderId = od.OrderId'' what does that or do, because its  showing as an error on mysql

Comment: I got so caught up in the acronym `or` for `OrderRecords` I didn't even realize I was using a reserved word. Fixed, see my edited answer.

Comment: i am confused here 
'FROM   OrderRecords orec'  i thuoght orec is just the same as OrderRecords in your answer?

Comment: @benjiWong yes - `orec` is an alias, just so I don't have to write the long `OrderRecords` each time.

Comment: if i wanna use "where", where should i put them? like if i wanna select only specific CreateTime range

Comment: nvm, i think i figured it out already, thanks alot for the help!